# vaadin legacy-styles.css doesn't load in IE8

Tags: java, css, vaadin, modernizr, ie8-compatibility-mode

I am using vaadin to create a web app. I want to import **legacy-styles.css** into my **styles.css**

my styles.css is as follow:

```
@import "../reindeer/legacy-styles.css";

.v-app {
    background: yellow;
}
```

Then use morderniz to targer IE8

```
Element head = response.getDocument().head();

        Element meta = head.appendElement("meta");
        meta.attr("name", "viewport");
        meta.attr("content", "width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1");


        // Meta tag to force IE8 to standard mode
        String ie8Meta = "<meta http-equiv=\"X-UA-Compatible\" content=\"IE=edge,chrome=1\">";
        head.prepend(ie8Meta);

// some other stuffs ...

        // Adding modernizr library to target ie8
        // http://modernizr.com/docs/
        String modernizr = "<script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/modernizr/2.6.2/modernizr.min.js\"></script>";
        head.prepend(modernizr);
```

Strangely, the legacy-styles loaded properly in IE10. Then legacy-styles.css doesn't load in IE8

The error reported is

```
com.vaadin.client.VConsole
SEVERE: CSS files may have not loaded properly.
```

I have tried to rearrange moderniz.js (using append instead of prepend) but didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Before we dig into the problem at hand, using `@import` is a super bad idea. While it is a convenient thing to do for you, it means that every single user that comes to your site will have to download a file (the document itself), in order to download another file (the one containing the `@import` string) *just* to download yet another file. In addition to DNS resolution and tcp handshakes, you are looking at possibly up to a dozen round trips between your server and their computer just to get this one single document. 
It would be much better to use a css precompiler, such as sass or less, and concatenating the older file with the new one into a single, compressed, file.

Next, modernizr shouldn't be used to target IE8, or any browser for that matter. That is actually completely against the purpose of Modernizr - which specializes in feature detection, rather than browser detection. That means that rather than saying you want to "target IE8", you would think more along the lines of wanting to "target browsers lacking feature X" (svg, geolocation, rounded corners, etc).

That being said, there are a number of reasons to specifically target versions of internet explorer, but modernizr is not the way to do it. The more correct way to do this would be using IE's conditional classes

```
<!--[if IE 8]>
    //IE specific stlyes here
<![endif]-->
```

Nothing you have shown has anything to do with IE specific code, and since modernizr doesn't add any features itself, there it isn't really clear why IE 10 would do anything different at all.